# Primefaces prevent click event closing menubar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

When i click on the inputText in submenu in menubar dropdown disappears.
But i need to fill inputText's before closing the dropdown.

```
<p:menubar styleClass="searchMenu" toggleEvent="click">
    <p:submenu label="Search places" icon="ui-icon-document">
        <p:menuitem>
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="label, value">
                <h:outputText value="#{text['id']}" />
                <p:inputText placeholder="Enter keyword" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```